# Not counting spaces as words in c

Tags: c, frequency, counting, words, letter

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long c;
    unsigned long line;
    unsigned long word;
    char ch;

    c = 0;
    line = 0;
    word = 0;

    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        c ++;
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            line ++;
        }
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n' || ch =='\'')
        {
            word ++;
        }
    }
    printf( "%lu %lu %lu\n", c, word, line );
    return 0;
}
```

My program works fine for the most part, but when I add extra spaces, it counts the spaces as extra words.  So for example,

```
How      are       you?
```

is counted as 10 words, but I want it to count as 3 words instead.  How could I modify my code to get it to work?

Comment: You have to modify your logic to *not* count (i.e. not increment `word`) when you see consecutive white-spaces.

Comment: That's becaue you have coded `if (ch == ' ' ...) word++;`. Every space you read, will increment the word count.

Comment: this line: while((ch = getchar()) != EOF) will fail because ch is defined as a char and EOF is an int that is longer than a char, so the comparison will always result in false, so the loop would never exit.

Comment: perhaps add an bool that is true when in a word (set true when a non space char is encountered) and set false when a space char is encountered.  Then only increment the word count when the bool is true and the encountered char is a space.  Otherwise just step to the next char.

Comment: in some OSs, (windows, DOS) the '\n' is actually two characters (which when read will fit into an int value and will be read as a single char count.)  so, again, the variable that holds the read char needs to be an integer.

Comment: I strongly suggest using descriptive variable names.  I.E. 'charCount' rather than 'c'.  This will save you (and everyone else, like the maintainer of the code and persons that are trying to understand your code) hours and hours of time.

Comment: Note that `++` should be attached to the expression it is incrementing — not separated from it by a space.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is one possible solution:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long c;
    unsigned long line;
    unsigned long word;
    char ch;
    char lastch = -1;

    c = 0;
    line = 0;
    word = 0;

    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        c ++;
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            line ++;
        }
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n' || ch =='\'')
        {
            if (!(lastch == ' ' && ch == ' '))
            {
                word ++;
            }
        }
        lastch = ch;
    }
    printf( "%lu %lu %lu\n", c, word, line );
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helped, good luck!

Comment: Shouldn't `lastch = ch;` be at the end of the loop, but with `lastch = -1` before the loop starts?

Comment: Thaïs does not work if words are separated by multiple newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to count words and between them several spaces the program will count only the words and not the several spaces also as words
here is the code:

`nbword` is the number of words, `c` is the character typed and `prvc` is the previously typed character.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int nbword = 1;
    char c, prvc = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ')
        {
            nbword++;
        }
        if(c == prvc && prvc == ' ')
            nbword-;
        if(c == '\n')
        {
            printf("%d\n", nbword);
            nbword = 1:
        }
        prvc = c;
    }
    return 0:
}
```

Comment: Please do not include images of your code and include the code itself posted in. You may want to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46503695/edit) your answer.